# Going back to previous object in array with back button in v-for

Tags: vue.js

I have a component with a v-for div. each item has a click function access their respective children object. I need to have a back button that would refresh the v-for div but using the ParentId of the current item I'm in.

Scan view:

```
<template>
  <div p-0 m-0>
    <div v-show="!currentItem" class="scanBreadcrumbs">
      <h2>Show location</h2>
    </div>

    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :item="item">
      <SubScan
        v-show="currentItem && currentItem.id === item.id"
        :item="item"
      ></SubScan>
      <p
        class="locationBox"
        @click="swapComponent(item)"
        v-show="path.length === 0"
      >
        {{ item.title }}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
import { SubScan } from "@/components/scan";

export default {
  name: "Scan",
  components: {
    SubScan
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getResourceHierarchy", "getIsDarkMode", "getFontSize"])
  },
  methods: {
    swapComponent(item) {
      this.path.push(item.title);
      this.currentItem = item;
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    currentItem: null,
    path: [],
    items: [
      {
        parentId: null,
        id: 11,
        title: "Location 1",
        items: [
          {
            parentId: 11,
            id: 4324,
            title: "Row 1",
            items: [
              {
                parentId: 4324,
                id: 4355,
                title: "Row 1.1",
                items: [
                  {
                    parentId: 4355,
                    id: 64645,
                    title: "Row 1.2",
                    items: [
                      {
                        parentId: 64645,
                        id: 7576657,
                        title: "Row 1.3",
                        items: [
                          {
                            parentId: 7576657
                            id: 8686,
                            title: "Row 1.4",
                            items: [
                              {
                                parentId: 8686,
                                id: 234324,
                                title: "QR Code"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
};
</script>
```

SubScan component where the back button is:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="scanBreadcrumbs">
      <h2 v-show="path">{{ path.join(" / ") }}</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="showList" v-for="item in itemChildren" :key="item.id">
        <p class="locationBox" @click="swapComponent(item)">
          {{ item.title }}
        </p>
        <div class="backButton">
          <v-icon @click="swapPrevious(item)" class="arrow"
            >fa-arrow-left</v-icon
          >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SubScan",
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    currentItem: null,
    secondaryPath: [],
    parentPath: []
  }),
  methods: {
    swapComponent(item) {
      console.log(item.parentId);
      this.path.push(item.title);
      this.parentPath.push(this.currentItem);
      this.currentItem = item;
    },
    swapPrevious(item) {
      console.log(item);
      this.path.pop(this.currentItem.title);

      this.currentItem = item.id;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    items(currentItem) {
      return this.currentItem ? this.item.items : this.item.items;
    },
    itemChildren(currentItem) {
      return this.currentItem ? this.currentItem.items : this.item.items;
    },
    path() {
      return this.secondaryPath.concat(this.item.title);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I can only go back to the children of the object I clicked on in Scan view.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by assigning parent objects to each children. Then I
moved everything to Scan.vue for simplicity. This is my first project using Vue
so things might not be optimal. Scan.vue

```
<template>
  <div p-0 m-0>
    <div class="scanBreadcrumbs">
      <h2 v-show="path">{{ path.join("/") }}</h2>
      <h2 v-if="path.length === 0">Show location</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div v-for="item in items">
        <p class="locationBox" @click="swapComponent(item)">
          {{ item.title }}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div v-if="path.length > 0">
        <div class="backButton">
          <v-icon @click="swapPrevious()" class="arrow">fa-arrow-left</v-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "Scan",

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getResourceHierarchy", "getIsDarkMode", "getFontSize"])
  },
  methods: {
    swapComponent(item) {
      this.path.push(item.title);
      this.currentItem = item;
      this.items = this.currentItem.items;
    },
    assignParent(children, parent) {
      children.forEach(item => {
        item.Parent = parent;
        var parentTitle = "";
        if (parent) parentTitle = parent.title;
        if (item.items) {
          this.assignParent(item.items, item);
        }
      });
    },
    swapPrevious() {
      if (this.currentItem.parentId === null) {
        this.items = this.initialItems;
        this.path.pop(this.currentItem.title);
      } else {
        this.currentItem = this.currentItem.Parent;
        this.items = this.currentItem.items;
        this.path.pop(this.currentItem.title);
      }
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.assignParent(this.items, null);
    this.initialItems = this.items;
  },
  data: () => ({
    currentItem: null,
    path: [],
    initialItems: [],
    items: [
      {
        parentId: null,
        id: 11,
        title: "Location 1",
        items: [
          {
            parentId: 11,
            id: 4324,
            title: "Row 1",
            items: [
              {
                parentId: 4324,
                id: 4355,
                title: "Row 1.1",
                items: [
                  {
                    parentId: 4355,
                    id: 64646,
                    title: "Row 1.2",
                    items: [
                      {
                        parentId: 64646,
                        id: 7576657,
                        title: "Row 1.3",
                        items: [
                          {
                            parentId: 7576657,
                            id: 8686,
                            title: "Row 1.4",
                            items: [
                              {
                                parentId: 8686,
                                id: 12313,
                                title: "Row 1.5",
                                items: [
                                  {
                                    parentId: 12313,
                                    id: 234324,
                                    title: "QR Code"
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```